# "My Documents/My Pictures" deleted on XP. "My Documents" copied on W7. "My Picture" now phantom

Tags: windows

Any help on a issue probably related to deleted system folders would be terrific:

- My old computer did run XP.
- On my old computer, I deleted "My documents/My images" -- never had any problem there.
- I just bought a new computer running Windows 7.
- Did copy all my files from old XP computer to new W7 computer, including "My documents/*.*".

Now issue on new W7 computer:

- "Documents" folder has all normal W7 folders, all looks normal.
- However, allway sync always stops as it can't access "C:\Users\chambre\Documents\My images".
- Yet this "My images" document does not show (neither with cmd: dir /a, neither with showing hidden files, ...).
- No trace of that "My images" in the registry either.
- Tried a CHKDSK.
- If I try to create a foldes named "My images", W7 tells me it exists already, proposes to merge which I tried, but still no "My Images" showing up at all. (so it is not an Allway Sync issue, but a Windows issue).

So now I have a phantom folder, which I can't delete, which does not show up everywhere, but which is quite annoying as if makes Allway Sync (at least) hang-up.

Nothing life threatening, yet quite annoying.

Any clue?

Thanks a lot.

PS: same issue with previously deleted "My music" and "My videos"

Comment: Have you tried `cd My pictures` or `rd "My pictures"`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `My Images` folder in Windows (XP or 7). There is a `My Pictures` folder, but not Images. That may have been added by a third-party program. This is particularly true since you specified that the `My Images` folder is in the `Documents` folder. By default, Windows does not put *anything* in the `Documents` folder, so everything in there was created by you or your programs.

Moreover, there is no actual `My Pictures` folder either (that is, there is no `C:\Users\chambre\My Pictures`). Instead there is a folder named `Pictures` in the user profile which contains a file named `desktop.ini`. Windows opens `desktop.ini`, reads the line `LocalizedResourceName`, and displays the corresponding value (the “friendly name”) in Windows Explorer in place of the actual folder name. In Explorer, you see `C:\Users\chambre\My Pictures`, but at the command-prompt, you see `C:\Users\chambre\Pictures`. It’s the same with `Music / My Music` and `Videos / My Videos`. Assuming the program that created the directory copied Windows’ behavior, search for `\Images` instead of `\My Images`.

If you get an *already exists* error when trying to create the directory, then you already copied the old ones, but they are probably just set to be hidden and your new Windows 7 installation has the *show hidden* option off (the default setting). You can toggle it as so:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> to open the *Folder Options* (or Run `control folders`)
2. Switch to the *Views* tab
3. Select *Show hidden files, folders, and drives*
4. `[OK]`

Comment: my mistake for the name which I translated wrong, but the underlying issue remains. Just read "My pictures" instead of "My images". The point is that there is this folder now in W7 which is not displayed in C:\Users\chambre\Documents\, yet there is a trace of it somwhow since Allway Syncs hangs on it, and since I can't create a folder with that name.

Comment: @user155298, it doesn’t matter what it’s called; Windows does not put anything in `My Documents`, so it was created by one of your programs (unless of course you meant `C:\Users\chambre\My Pictures` instead of `C:\Users\chambre\Documents\My Pictures`, in which case, it’s the second and/or third paragraphs of my answer).

Comment: I did try the Show Hidden Files -- not there either. And as said neither visible with the CMD dir /a.

Comment: Then it’s the second paragraph.

Comment: neither. I understand that in W7 there is no Documents/My Pictures. I had "My Document/My Picture" under XP and this was a system folder I believe. In W7, I have the right picture folder in chambre/My Picture even though it displays in a different cosmetic name as you mentioned. The issue remains: if I am in "Document", I can't create nor delete a folder named "My Pictures".

Comment: Did you try `Documents\Pictures`?

Comment: The issue is clearly with the exact folder name "C:\Users\chambre\Documents\Mes images", as this is the one triggering the error message with Allway Sync. I just don't know how to delete this folder as it appears nowhere. I created then deleted Documents\Pictures ok, but can't do the same with Documents\mes images. I know it sounds silly, easy fix, just make this folder display then kill it, but it won't

Comment: You said that you couldn’t see it with `dir /a`, but does it show the *other* items correctly?

Comment: yes, all other folder show up correctly. it even shows indeed the hidden files, the Jonction, the desktop.ini, etc. but no sign of this one file. it has got to be there somewhere since I can't create a folder with that name... maybe can I edit desktop.ini?

Comment: sorry, I think I got it. Indeed the three folders that cause problem do appear in DIR /A as <JONCTION>, all three of them. What can I do with that?

Comment: Did you try `dir "mes images"`? To see what’s *inside* the phantom directory?

Comment: Look in the brackets, it should tell you where the junctions point (e.g., `"mes images" [C:\Users\chambre\pictures]`)

Comment: I see it as a Jonction. It will not let me do a DIR on it

Comment: the jonction goes to [C:\users\chambre\Pictures]

Comment: I tried to create the folder C:\users\chambre\Pictures again (which works) and then run Allsync hoping that since there is now a folder linked to \mes images Allsync would passs but it stillhangs on \mes images

Comment: Have you accidentally checked the *don’t follow junctions* option? I don’t know if AllSync has it, but Michael definitely put it in his other program AllDup, so I imagine that AllSync has it too.

Comment: I will check this when I get back home. I doubt I did since this is all freshly installed, all following default settings. I have also found out more about Jonctions and will try to remove one and see if that fixes. thanks for the help Synetech.

Comment: I don't seem to have that option. After some more searches, I think there is nothing wrong with the Jonctions. I read I should switch the Owner of the folder and that where the jonction points at to Admin instead of System. Will give it a try.

Comment: Try opening a command-prompt, then navigate to your profile (e.g., `cd c:\users\chambre`), then just do a simple `dir /s/ad *image* *picture*` and see what you find.

Comment: A sledgehammer solution: create a new `Documents` folder (e.g., `Documents.new`), copy everything (including `desktop.ini`, which is a hidden **system** file), then rename `Documents` to `Documents.old` and `Documents.new` to `Documents`.  See whether everything works, then delete `Documents.old`.  (Of course, _that_ might give you problems, too.)

Comment: @Scott, what if the folder is in use? That leads to the next idea: boot into safe-mode and see whether you can see it.